# Disable SQL Server replacement of * with column names in views?

Tags: sql-server

I've started with SQL Server recently and I noticed it autocompletes * in views with all the table column names. Eg: When I save a query such  as this:

```
SELECT * FROM Users
```

SQL Server automatically replace the asterysk with all the column names in the table.

```
SELECT Name, LastName, Birthday, Whatever FROM Users
```

This is a bit problematic when working with tables with a lot of fields. Morover it causes problems when chaning column names since they have to be updated automatically in all views.

Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Comment: No, there isn't such a feature. You might want to read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list) (Some good info in the comments also)

Comment: Do like me - disable entire autocompletion feature :) Otherwise - `select *` will be compiled to column list (using ordinal positions!) internally and using such views may result in strange results after underlying tables structure change anyway.

Comment: I don't see any views in your question. Are you really talking about [views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx)?

Comment: I believe the OP is using the visual view designer (right click on Views, New View). If you put a * in there, it expands the column names. My suggestion is to NEVER use the built in view designer as it can emit some horrid SQL. Hand coding your statements is better, and you are in more control.